# (Google Embed API) How to make DataChart responsive

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to make a google analytics embed datachart responsive but it does not really work so well. I found several "solutions" that could not solve my problem, so I'll ask this question here.

I'm using Google Embed API - I'm not asking for google Charts since I know you can just redraw them, but if I do that get the message `message:"User Rate Limit Exceeded"` in no time - I'm not using Google Chart Container, [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#datachart) is the documentation for DataCharts but I could not find a "resize" function

I've also tried to `options: {width: '100%'}` but this only works for the first rendering. I can resize the Datachart [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/) all day long without reaching the data transfer limit and I would like to know how to achieve this.

Thank you very much